# Android TextView update

Tags: android

Hi
I am trying to update a textview to notify the user when the GPS coordinates have been logged.
My problem is that I need to access the location infomation from another class and I cannot directly edit the textview from anything apart from the onCreate class.

here is my code:

```
public class Location extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 

        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(); 


        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener); 

        } 



        public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 

        { 

        private final String TAG = null;

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              location.getLatitude(); 

                location.getLongitude(); 

                String Text = "My current location is: " + "Latitud = " + location.getLatitude() + "Longitud = " + location.getLongitude();

                try
                {
                    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File gps = new File(root, "log.txt");




                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter(gps,true)) ;

                TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tv.setText(Text);
                out.write(Text);
                out.write("");
                out.close();

                }


                catch (IOException e) {


                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());

                }

        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i have a similar problem with a textview, i'm using a gps class, and i have on the screen more textview like a position of interest that this textview move on the screen;

i remove all textview and after add again textview, so i can update a position of textview; but i can't execute a onclick method because the textview are add and remove continuously

Answer (score 0):

Store the location information in a model object or a singleton, then access that information from the other class?

Comment: you mean create a static String text and use that in the onCreate class to update the TextView?

Answer (score 0):

Set Handler in activity class, and pass it to handler, when handler is called, send a message to the Handler with your String. (The handler will update the GUI).
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html.

Edit: BTW you can change the GUI from outside the class, but you have to be on the same Thread.

Comment: I am not using more then 1 thread and with current code the TextView does not update inside the onLocationUpdate class. I tested it by updating it inside the onCreate class and it works so its just not working in the other class.

Comment: I added it as a comment since it didn't matter in your case. Actually, the call to onLocationChanged() is from another thread, therefore, the all listener runs as part of another thread.

Comment: ah ok strange thing is that if I create the same app and use toasts under android 2.2 or 2.1 the toast displays fine in the onChange class but on 2.3 the toast will not show.

Comment: anyone got any ideas on that?? why toast does not work on 2.3 but works on 2.2?